# NumberLinePlot with Exponential

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
Clear[f, x]
f[x_] = Exp[1/x]
```

Now, the question is "where is the derivative negative?" I managed to get the Reduce command to work by adding Reals.

```
Reduce[f'[x] < 0, x, Reals]
```

Which gave this answer:

```
x != 0
```

However, NumberLinePlot gave me an empty line:

```
NumberLinePlot[f'[x] < 0, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

So, is there a way to say to the NumberLinePlot "use the Reals"?

Comment: You can use the result of `Reduce` directly: `NumberLinePlot[Reduce[f'[x] < 0, x, Reals], {x, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @C.E. Nice answer. Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler function first:

```
g[x_] := x^4
g'[x]
```

> 4 x^3

```
Reduce[g'[x] < 0]
```

> x < 0

```
NumberLinePlot[g'[x] < 0, x]
```

[image]

---

Now let

```
f[x_] := Exp[1/x]
f'[x]
```

> -(E^((1/x))/x^2)

```
red = Reduce[f'[x] < 0, x]
```

[image]

I guess that this output is too complicated for `NumberLinePlot` to interpret, so when

```
NumberLinePlot[f'[x] < 0, {x, -2, 2}]
```

it produces an empty axes. With

```
red = Reduce[f'[x] < 0, Reals]
```

> x != 0

it knows what to do:

```
NumberLinePlot[red, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]